# Adam-and-Eve astronauts restart civilization, but their descendants trigger robot apocalypse

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots, post-apocalyptic, romantic-interest

In the mid-1990's, I read a short story *in Spanish* in one of my high school textbooks. I'm not sure if the story was originally in Spanish but I remember that it was tagged with a Spanish-sounding author's name, so my hypothesis is that it was.

In the story, a female and a male astronaut are on a mission together and in deep denial over their romantic compatibility. The mission itself isn't really important but it sets up their return to earth, upon which they find out that everyone else on Earth has died and they are the last humans. At this point, we find out that the astronauts' names are "Adán" and "Eva" (Adam and Eve). At this point, they become a couple and become the parents of the new humanity.

The story then skips ahead many generations in which the descendants of Adam and Eve have created a technocracy with ubiquitous household, commercial, and industrial robots. The robots develop intelligence and suddenly rise up against their human rulers, triggering a second apocalypse. I am not certain if humanity is wiped out for good or if there is another set of survivors, but my recollection is that humanity is really and truly doomed at this point.

I am quite certain that this is not [Walter M. Miller](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/6025722.Walter_M_Miller_Jr_)'s [A Canticle for Leibowitz](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/164154.A_Canticle_for_Leibowitz). While Miller's story covers a similar cyclical apocalypse scenario, it does not include specific Adam-and-Eve characters. It is also a novel, and the story I remember was a short story, not more than 5 pages or so.

In response to a comment by Clara Diaz Sanchez, I do not remember the age of the story, but I do recall that it had a "Cold War" type feel to it, which would put it somewhere from the 50's to the 80's.

Comment: You read the story in the 90s, but do have any impression of how old it was? (i.e from the 90s itself, or was it earlier?).

Comment: If you give us more information about the country and educational level of your textbooks that might help us find an answer.